# How to inverse cumulative sum in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sum

I have a rather simple problem to which I cannot seem to find any solution. I have looked at many similar questions online but their solutions don't work in my case.

I have a pandas dataset in the following format

```
        CountryCode  ConfirmedCases  ConfirmedDeaths        date
   335         ABW          4872.0             45.0  2020-12-01
   336         ABW          4902.0             45.0  2020-12-02
   337         ABW          4923.0             45.0  2020-12-03
   338         ABW          4942.0             45.0  2020-12-04
   339         ABW          4957.0             45.0  2020-12-05
```

**ConfirmedCases and ConfirmedDeaths are both measured as cumulative sums by CountryCode, but I need the daily cases and daily deaths by CountryCode**. This requires that I compute the difference between confirmed cases at time *t* and time *t-1* for every country in my dataset--i.e. the difference between the number of cases today and the day before in the same country. Ideally, I would like a solution that allows me to register the daily number of cases and daily number of deaths by country as two new variables in the dataset. As a result, I would like something that should look like the following:

```
        CountryCode  ConfirmedCases  ConfirmedDeaths        date    DailyCases    Daily Deaths
   335         ABW          4872.0             45.0  2020-12-01     15            0
   336         ABW          4902.0             45.0  2020-12-02     30            0
   337         ABW          4923.0             45.0  2020-12-03     21            0
   338         ABW          4942.0             45.0  2020-12-04     19            0
   339         ABW          4957.0             45.0  2020-12-05     15            0
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `df.groupby('CountryCode').diff()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quang Hoang's solution is right except you should then replace `NaN` values with the initial value for each country:

```
df['DailyCases'] = df.groupby('CountryCode')['ConfirmedCases'].diff()
df['DailyCases'] = df['DailyCases'].fillna(df['ConfirmedCases'])
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Would it be necessary to group by country code and date, considering that my dataset is a panel (daily observations for multiple countries for almost a year)?

Comment: No, if you group by Country and Date you will only have a single row in each of your groups and so there will be nothing to de-accumulate. On the contrary, if each of your groups contains case and death values for different dates, you will be able to compute the differences correctly for each country. Just try it :)